# Not able to call method under success of api using .bind(this)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to call method on success of my ajax api call. I have stored this(context) inside local variable that but still not able to get context of that view and getting error that.setPdfUrl is not a function. And important thing is i am calling method by pub/sub mechanism.
My code looks like -

```
kf.Events.off('getPdfUrl');
kf.Events.on('getPdfUrl', this.getPdfUrl);

  getPdfUrl: function() {
   var that = this;
   $.ajax({
     url: kf.Settings.fileGeneratorUrl() + "/ikfc/singlereport",
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
       //content
     },
     success: function(result) {
        that.setPdfUrl(kf.Settings.fileGeneratorUrl() + '/download?guid=' + 
        result.Message);
     }
   });

  }.bind(this),

setPdfUrl: function(url){
    this.pdfUrl = url;
  }
```

Getting

> Uncaught TypeError: that.setPdfUrl is not a function

Comment: Got solution by binding context at initialize - kf.Events.on('getPdfUrl', this.getPdfUrl.bind(this));

Comment: It is encouraged to write an answer to your own question when you find a solution. Comments are meant to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Done. I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by binding context at initialize -

```
kf.Events.on('getPdfUrl', this.getPdfUrl.bind(this))
```

Comment: If `kf.Events.on` is [`Backbone.Events.on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) then you could also say `kf.Events.on('getPdfUrl', this.getPdfUrl, this)`.

Comment: Yes, kf.Events.on is Backbone.Events.on. Thanks a lot and this one is useful.

Comment: I don't understand how the code in question is any different from this, unless the code above is being executed in different context, which is not clear from the code in question, which looks like broken code. In short this question and answer is only going to be useful to yourself and not anybody else...

Answer (score -1):

You can just move following lines.

getPdfUrl: function() {
   var that = this;

Change to

var that = this;
 getPdfUrl: function() {

it will work, there are multiple ways to achieve this. but for now, you can use this.